# Does TTS.speechRate() affect when synthesizing to an audio file?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, speech, rate

I have two methods, `setSpeechRate(Float value)` and `public int synthesizeToFile(final CharSequence text, final Bundle params, final File file, final String utteranceId)`, and I am hoping to find a way to synthesize those files within a different speech rate.

Therefore, the first step is to call to `setSpeechRate(4.0f)` (which returns `0` or `SUCCESS`). Nevertheless, when I synthesize the `String` into a file within the same `Text-to-Engine`, and I play it using `MediaPlayer`, I can not play it faster than the default value `speechRate = 1`.

I was hoping that, since the `speechRate` is actually updated to `4.0`, the resulting file would also have the same rate. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#setSpeechRate(float)), setSPeechRate has no effect on "pre-recorded speech."  Its a strange and confusing choice of words, but I'm assuming that by "pre-recorded," they mean speech created using synthesizeToFile.

It makes sense because slower speech would result in large files, and it would be difficult to play the same file at various speeds.

So it looks like you have to use the player to control speech rate.